# How do you properly pass a bytes object to a new Thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm attempting to read a 1GB file, chunk it into 4MB files, and upload those individually using multiple threads.  However, I don't think I'm passing the "chunk" object correctly.  I suspect this line may be incorrect:

```
threading.Thread(target=UploadFile, args=[filename, chunk]).start()
```

Do I need to copy "chunk" before passing it as a parameter?  My concern is that "chunk" is not thread-safe in this example, and as a result, the uploaded chunks will not be consistent with the source data.

Here is the full method:

```
def ChunkAndUpload(inputFilename):
    global runningThreadCount
    maxThreads = 10
    chunkSize = 1024*1024*4
    index = 0
    with open(inputFilename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunkSize)
            if not chunk: break
            filename = str(index) + ".dat"
            while (True):
                if (runningThreadCount<maxThreads):
                    runningThreadCount += 1
                    threading.Thread(target=UploadFile, args=[filename, chunk]).start()
                    break
                else:
                    sleep(.1)
            index+=1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Code is incomplete, you've not reported any error, what you expect to happen, what actually happens.

Comment: What seems to be going wrong - please clarify?

Comment: My concern is that "chunk" is not thread-safe, and thus the uploaded chunks will be inconsistent with the source data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bytes` is an immutable type (as is `str` for that matter). Immutable types are not subject to race conditions (except in the sense that you could completely replace a shared name with a reference to a completely different object).

As soon as you do `args=[filename, chunk]`, you've made a new `list` that "coincidentally" contains a reference to the same `bytes` as `chunk` does; from that moment on, `chunk` can be reassigned and it will have no effect on the contents of that `list`, whether or not the `Thread` has successfully launched.

Answer (score 3):

Even if arguments are passed by reference to the new thread (and thus changes to chunks would show in the other thread) your code does not *write* to the chunks byte array, it simple takes a reference to a new bytes object each time from `f.read`. Thus, it seems that you should be safe, although if the upload is slow enough you might be reading the whole file into memory at once.